# How to use variable as range upper bound

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following problem in a bash script. I'm trying to use a variable `N` as the upper bound in a simple range, like

```
#!/bin/bash

N=10

for n in {1..$N};
do
    echo $n
done;
```

However, instead of displaying each number in the loop, the code above literally displays `{1..10}`. If I change `$N` to its value, i.e. `10`, things work as expected. How can I overcome this and use the variable as the upper limit of the range?

Comment: This site appears to have an answer for you.  https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-iterate-over-a-variable-range-of-numbers-in-bash/

Comment: My bad, thanks for pointing out the dupe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this, instead, do that :

```
n=10
for ((i=0; i<=n; i++)); do
    echo $i
done
```

or :

```
n=10
for i in $(seq 0 $n); do
    echo $i
done
```